# Running code without ssh in beaglebone black

Tags: bash, ssh, startup, beagleboneblack

**I want to run some code in Beaglebone black without doing ssh when I apply power.**

I have tried putting some commands to run the code in `~/.bashrc` file but it only works when I login using `ssh`. I have tried same thing with `/etc/rc.local` file but didn't work even after ssh.

I have also tried `@reboot my_command` in `crontab -e` but it also requires me to login using ssh
 Any suggestions??

EDIT:

```
root@beaglebone:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie

root@beaglebone:~# ps aux | grep cron | grep -v grep
root       295  0.0  0.3   4428  1988 ?        Ss   15:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

Output of `crontab -e`: last few lines

```
root@beaglebone:~# crontab -e
    # For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
    #
    # m h  dom mon dow   command


#@reboot /root/wiringBone-master/library/main           not working

#*/5 * * * * /root/wiringBone-master/library/main       works
```

`main` is the script I want to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`crontab -e` method worked!!. My script required two overlays to execute the code which I didn't load that's why my `@reboot command` didn't work. I solved my problem by adding required overlays.

```
@reboot config-pin overlay cape-universaln
@reboot config-pin overlay BB-ADC
@reboot /root/wiringBone-master/library/main
```

And now my code works on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about beagle bone, but on a normal Linux system you'd likely do this with either an init script, or, more easily, in a cron script set to run at boot.

You'll have to check if you're environment would support either of those.  Even if it doesn't have cron, it is probably running some sort of init (likely to be the thing starting SSH on boot, but YMMV).

Comment: It supports `cron` as well as `init`. Can you explain how to use them in my case. Say `execute_some` command at `some_location` at startup.

Comment: Do you know which flavor of cron it uses?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188042/running-a-script-during-booting-startup-init-d-vs-cron-reboot might shed some light on syntax.

Comment: Tried `crontab -e` and `init.d` but I still need to login using ssh to execute my code at startup.

Comment: You should update your question with the specifics of what you've tried.

Comment: Added some extra info

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17375663/cron-job-to-send-ip-of-beaglebone-black-at-every-reboot-to-my-email-is-not-fir 
Looks like it should work?  Or maybe cron version changed.  Otherwise, init script like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854705/executing-a-script-on-statup-using-beaglebone-black might work for you, but probably more effort than cron

Comment: Your crontab lines are *commented out*! You need to remove the `#` in front of the respective lines!

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/rc.local` is a quick way. Make sure to launch into background and don't prevent the script from finishing.

Writing a proper systemd service file would be better though.

Comment: Added some extra info

Comment: `Didn't work` is insufficient. You need to at least make an effort to understand *why* things don't work and post *exactly* what you did. E.g. the rc.local script contains a last line of `exit 0` by default, and you *MUST obviously* put your commands *before that*.

Comment: yes I took care of `exit 0` line. crontab method worked!!. I write an answer.